# PHP datetime formatting in echo

Tags: php, date

PHP noob. Having trouble getting a PHP date format to execute here:

```
echo "<div class='column'>"; 
echo $row['date']; 
echo "</div>";
```

I tried the below but no luck.

```
echo ".date('d/m/y', strtotime($row['date']))";
```

Comment: How is this not working? Do you not see anything? What is the value of `$row['date']`? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: strtotime doesn't need timestamps. It should read any valid date string.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
echo date('d/m/y', strtotime($row['date']));
```

The problem is

```
echo ".date('d/m/y', strtotime($row['date']))";
      ^............

$date = '2014-01-31';
echo ".date('d/m/y', strtotime($date))";
```

The output will be `.date('d/m/y', strtotime(2014-01-31))`

It will treat all as a string except the variable inside "".

Comment: Do you even know what they;re problem is? How does this fix their first block of code?

Comment: because he was wrapping php functions inside of double quotations. php only reads variables inside of double quotes, not functions.